# Can I set variable monthly payment amounts through PayPal REST API's billing plan/agreement? On existing agreements?

Tags: recurring-billing, paypal-rest-sdk

I entered this as an [issue on the PayPal-PHP-SDK github](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/277) but it's rather time sensitive at this point.

Our goal is a subscription service that monthly charges users a value they select for each content update during that month. A $1 subscriber would pay $8 if there were 8 updates, for example.

Our implementation so far (which is already live with a number of subscribers) is using the PayPal-PHP-SDK / REST API to create a Billing Plan for each subscriber with a payment definition set to an amount calculated to be the maximum potential monthly charge. I then expected to be able to use `Agreement->setBalance()` to lower the value to the actual intended charge and then `Agreement->billBalance()` to process the payment.

Unfortunately due to time pressures we launched without verifying this was a viable implementation, and I've discovered that those functions are only for unpaid/delinquent balances. The `start_date` on our plans is April 1, and we'll have had 4 content releases but we're set to charge our subscribers for the maximum possible 9 updates.

I've tried a variety of `Agreement->update()` and `Plan->update()` calls to change the monthly value, along the lines of:

```
$Patch = new PayPal\Api\Patch();
$Patch->setOp("replace")
    ->setPath("/payment_definitions/0/amount/value")
    ->setValue($patch_value);

$PatchRequest = new PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
$PatchRequest->addPatch($Patch);

$Plan = PayPal\Api\Plan::get($plan_id, $apiContext);
$Plan->update($PatchRequest, $apiContext);
```

which returns an exception with "validation_error: Invalid Path provided". Attempts to json encode the data path, up to and including the entire Plan object with  `$Patch->setPath("/")` instead give an exception with "MALFORMED_REQUEST - Incoming JSON request does not map to API request". I suspect most values cannot be updated on an executed agreement or activated plan.

However, I see through the merchant account's website that the monthly value can be manually updated, so I hold out hope that I'm simply going about my API requests the wrong way.

I've also tried creating a `Payment` object with `Transaction->setPurchaseUnitReferenceId($AgreementId)` since I'd read something about reference transactions being a potential solution, but I'm getting the same malformed request error:

```
$Item = new PayPal\Api\Item();
$Item->setCategory('DIGITAL')
    ->setPrice($pledge_value)
    ->setDescription($update_name);

$ItemList = new PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$ItemList->addItem($Item);

$Amount = new PayPal\Api\Amount();
$Amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($pledge_value);

$Transaction = new PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$Transaction->setPurchaseUnitReferenceId($AgreementId)
    ->setDescription($update_name)
    ->setAmount($Amount)
    ->setItemList($ItemList)
    ->setNotifyUrl($notify_url);

$Payer = new PayPal\Api\Payer();
$Payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$RedirectUrls = new PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$RedirectUrls->setReturnUrl($return_url)
    ->setCancelUrl($cancel_url);

$Payment = new PayPal\Api\Payment();
$Payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($Payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($RedirectUrls)
    ->addTransaction($Transaction);

$Payment->create($apiContext);
```

So is there a way to fix our current implementation and plans/agreements? Failing that, is there a REST API solution that I should have used / can try to migrate to? I'd like to avoid Classic API if possible.

Comment: I want to know this too. just bumped up on a requirement that user should be able to choose add-ons product on top of based plan.

Comment: Is there anything in the newer REST API or checkout.js that can help accomplish this?  Stripe and Braintree have the ability to create Customer objects and Payment Method tokens that can be used to charge the customer any amount at any time, as long as they initially consent.  It's not that rare of a circumstance to have auto-recharge type cases like Starbucks cards etc. where the amount is unknown ahead of time and different each time.  I'd be really surprised if the deprecated version was the only one to support this.